# Javascript Errors when loading Bootstrap Modal a second and third time that contains a form with drop downs

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-modal, django-autocomplete-light

I'm a complete beginner...please excuse the mess. Only been learning for about a month.

The structure is like this.

I have a nav.html template I've created for a top level menu across the site. It contains a drop down for creating New entries...and in this case a 'New Job'

Job has two special parts.

1. I've used Django-autocomplete-light for finding/creating new customers in the one form. This leverages select2 and some other javascript wizards
2. A google places autocomplete for finding site addresses

Everything worked fine as just opening in a fresh page. Then I decided I wanted to put the New Job form in to a modal instead. I'm an idiot.

I'm using non-modified bootstrap css and the js for it as well...but pulled them down to be local copies in my static folder. Same goes for jquery and popper.

Got it to actually work/pop up fine but then these happened in the background. Grabs from the google chrome console. These are the errors I see when just opening and closing without entering any data.

I started learning about the javascript event loop and it hurt my brain...but does this all have something to do with that? This kind of feels like things are loading...and then not unloading if I'm making any sense. Every example out there is based on using a button...and I've gone with a drop down selection but I don't feel like that should make any difference. Please help.

[Screenshot of the first run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Pc5.png)

[Screenshot of the second run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZJfR.png)

[Screenshot of the third run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brtKU.png)

Here's the code for all the bits n pieces. If I'm missing something, let me know.

NAV.HTML (contains the dropdown to trigger the modal....towards the bottom called "create-job")

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'%}">



    <title>Easy Insulation</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="{% static '/js/jquery.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/jqueryUI/jquery-ui.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/popper.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".create-job").modalForm({
                formURL: "{% url 'create_job' %}"
            });

        });

    </script>

    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="modal" data-backdrop="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="{% static '/images/LogowithText.png'%}" width="110" height="40" alt="Easy Insulation"
                loading="lazy">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Dashboard<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Planning<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">

                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Jobs
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'pipes' %}">Pipelines</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'job_list' %}">List</a>

                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">

                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Contacts
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Businesses</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contacts</a>

                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'prod_list' %}">Services<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="../admin">Admin<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Meh</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">
                New
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item submit-btn create-job" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button">Job</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Activity</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Organisation</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}
    You need to build some content here tups
    {% endblock %}
    {% block extra_content %}
    More space for stuff
    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the code for the Modal that pops up

NEWJOB.HTML

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/modal.css'%}">

</head>

<body>

  {% block content %}
 <script src="{% static '/js/googlepac.js'%}"></script>
  <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=IVEREMOVEDTHEKEYFORSHARINGPURPOSES&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>

  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Create New Job</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button id="disposeBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>

  </form>

  {% endblock %}
  {% block extra_content %}
  {{form.media}}
  {% endblock %}
</body>


</html>
```

This is the googlepac.js file

```
var autocomplete;

function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('id_site_address'), {types: ['address']});
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);
}
```

the query.bootstrap.modal.forms.js from some super smart bro on the internet.

```
/*
django-bootstrap-modal-forms
version : 1.5.0
Copyright (c) 2019 Uros Trstenjak
https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms
*/

(function ($) {

    // Open modal & load the form at formURL to the modalContent element
    var newForm = function (modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn) {
        $(modalID).find(modalContent).load(formURL, function () {
            $(modalID).modal("show");
            $(modalForm).attr("action", formURL);
            // Add click listener to the submitBtn
            addListeners(modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn);
        });
    };

    // Submit form callback function
    var submitForm = function(modalForm) {
      $(modalForm).submit();
    };

    var addListeners = function (modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn) {
        // submitBtn click listener
        $(submitBtn).on("click", function (event) {
            isFormValid(modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn, submitForm);
        });
        // modal close listener
        $(modalID).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
            $(modalForm).remove();
        });
    };

    // Check if form.is_valid() & either show errors or submit it
    var isFormValid = function (modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(modalForm).attr("method"),
            url: $(modalForm).attr("action"),
            // Serialize form data
            data: $(modalForm).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(submitBtn).prop("disabled", true);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if ($(response).find(errorClass).length > 0) {
                    // Form is not valid, update it with errors
                    $(modalID).find(modalContent).html(response);
                    $(modalForm).attr("action", formURL);
                    // Reinstantiate listeners
                    addListeners(modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn);
                } else {
                    // Form is valid, submit it
                    callback(modalForm);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.modalForm = function (options) {
        // Default settings
        var defaults = {
            modalID: "#modal",
            modalContent: ".modal-content",
            modalForm: ".modal-content form",
            formURL: null,
            errorClass: ".invalid",
            submitBtn: ".submit-btn"
        };

        // Extend default settings with provided options
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            // Add click listener to the element with attached modalForm
            $(this).click(function (event) {
                // Instantiate new modalForm in modal
                newForm(settings.modalID,
                    settings.modalContent,
                    settings.modalForm,
                    settings.formURL,
                    settings.errorClass,
                    settings.submitBtn);
            });
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: The first warning is because the XMLHttpRequest is deprecated, the second is because you have incluided the google maps script more than one, and the third is because jquery isn't loaded/defined

Comment: Yep...gathered all that from reading the errors too. So why do all the errors only show u after opening each time and not on the first run?

Comment: because only until in this moment you tried invoke the functions with this problems.